# asp.net RegularExpressionValidator and complex regular expression (case sensitive switch)

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

I'm using ASP's RegularExpressionValidator with a very complex regular expression. This one works already well:

```
(?=^.{10,}$)(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[+#<>;.,:|\\-@*!\"§$%&/()=?`´]).*$
```

But I have to extend it to add the check if the current username is part (case insensitive) of the password.

For example the user name is Meier the user shall not be allowed to create a password

> i012k34KmeIer567+

So I changed the expression to

```
(?=^.{10,}$)(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[+#<>;.,:|\\-@*!\"§$%&/()=?`´])(?i)(?!.*meier)(?-i).*$
```

and added that to `asp:RegularExpressionValidator` as `ValidationExpression`.

Unfortunately, when doing so, I get an error in my browser when adding a password:

```
"SyntaxError: invalid quantifier"
```

The problematic code the browser shows is:

```
function RegularExpressionValidatorEvaluateIsValid(val) {
    var value = ValidatorGetValue(val.controltovalidate);
    if (ValidatorTrim(value).length == 0)
        return true;
    **var rx = new RegExp(val.validationexpression);**
    var matches = rx.exec(value);
    return (matches != null && value == matches[0]);
}
```

The line with the `"**"` is the problematic one.

I also tried already `RegEx.IsMatch`, but there my regular expression works. Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this or can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Any help is very welcome! :) And please do not hesitate to ask if I described anything not well enough.

Comment: So what's your question/problem? Password or username?

Comment: I have to check case insensitive if the username appears in my password. So for this I need to extend the above regular expression.

Comment: If the part discussing about the password is irrelevant, can you edit it out? It is very confusing.

Comment: Okay I will make it more simple. But it is about username occurence in password.

Comment: You might find that this is easier to accomplish by associated multiple validator controls with the same field, rather than trying to cram everything into one validator.

Comment: Okay, then I still have the problem, that I have to define it as case insensitive. Somehow asp:RegularExpressionValidator does not like (?i)

Comment: So I added a RegularExpressionValidator only for the user name. It ended ab in a regexp

"(?i)^.(?!.*meier)(?!.*hans).*$"

But I still get the invalid quantifier error. I think my problem is really that I'm using the i-modifier wrong. Can anyone help with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you set `EnableClientScript="False"` to disable client-side validation, see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahwtc9e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), your expression will need to be valid for Javascript's regular expression engine.

That is why `var rx = new RegExp(val.validationexpression);` is causing an error, your expression is invalid.

Javascript does not support the inline case-sensitivity flags `(?i)` and `(?-i)` and your long character class needs revision

```
 [+#<>;.,:|\\@*!"§$%&/()=?`´-]
```

And as you can't turn on case-insensitivity just for the password negative look-ahead in Javascript, it would be better to test for the password separately.

Comment: Separately and EnableClientScript = "False" helped me both a lot. Thank you all very much! :)